# Reduce the distance between the numbering on the axis and the ticks

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I reduce the distance between the numbering of an axis and the ticks corresponding to them. I tried using pad=0 for the tick_params but it doesn't seem to work. Below is a reproducible (simplified) code of my issue (and the figure):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d 

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (10,10)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)

ax.set_xlabel("X" , fontsize=20)
ax.set_ylabel("Y", fontsize=20)
ax.set_zlabel("Z" , fontsize=20)

ax.view_init(azim=-20)

ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', pad=0)

x = np.arange(0,10,0.01)
y = np.ones(len(x))
z = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x,y,z)
```

Changing the values of pad seem to not have any effect. Note: I need the plot in that specific orientation (azim=-20). How can I achieve what I need? Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The pad argument also takes negative values to bring the ticklabels closer to the ticks.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d 

fig = plt.figure()
ax = axes3d.Axes3D(fig)

ax.set_xlabel("X" , fontsize=20)
ax.set_ylabel("Y", fontsize=20)
ax.set_zlabel("Z" , fontsize=20)

ax.view_init(azim=-20)

ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', pad=-5)

x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.01)
y = np.ones(len(x))
z = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x, y, z)
plt.show()
```

[image]

**EDIT**: Alternative outcome with set figure size and dpi value.

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d 

mpl.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = 10, 10
mpl.rcParams["figure.dpi"] = 100

fig = plt.figure()
ax = axes3d.Axes3D(fig)

ax.set_xlabel("X" , fontsize=20)
ax.set_ylabel("Y", fontsize=20)
ax.set_zlabel("Z" , fontsize=20)

ax.view_init(azim=-20)

ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', pad=-5)

x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.01)
y = np.ones(len(x))
z = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x, y, z)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Could it be a matter of matplotlib version? I tried values for pad between -100 and 100 and nothing changes. Also, I need to keep the ratio as in the original post (I added plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (10,10), to my code). Squeezing the plot on the z axis does indeed creates the illusion of number getting closer, but that is not what I need.

Comment: I am using matplotlib 3.2.1 and Python 3.8.3. For me the pad argument really has an effect (see my edit). Note that the "squeezing" is not only dependent on the figure size but also on the dpi setting. Only thing I needed to change in your code to make it work for me was the line `ax = axes3d.Axes3D(fig)`.